# how to poll in a header-value-router

Tags: spring-integration, polling

i cannot find out, how to configure a poller for header-value-router.

```
<int:header-value-router input-channel="splittedNewPaulaEvents" header-name="eventName" resolution-required="true">
    <int:mapping value="WORK_ORDER_CLOSE" channel="BE_WORK_ORDER_CLOSE" />
</int:header-value-router>
```

At startup i get the error:
*No poller has been defined for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.*

if i also add

```
<int:poller id="defaultPoller" default="true" fixed-rate="1000" />
```

The context starts, but it seems, that my router doesn't work? Is there a way to get more infos about the activities of the polling event or the header-value-router activities?

thanks

Comment: BTW, you can also add a specific poller to the router (`<int:poller fixed-delay="100" />`) right above the mapping entry. Turn on DEBUG logging to see message activity. You should see messages like `09:18:38.011 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'`. If a message arrives in the channel you will see the router being invoked